# Why would feature scaling cause overfitting?

Tags: logistic, out-of-sample, overfitting

I'm fitting a logistic regression to a simple two-feature dataset. The feature values range from about 1 to 100. When I scale the features (using scikit-learn StandardScaler), the in-sample performance improves significantly, but the out of sample performance drops. Why would feature scaling cause overfitting?

Comment: Are you scaling the out of sample test set in the same way? If you are normalizing, are the mins & maxs dissimilar? If you are standardizing, are the means & SDs dissimilar?

Comment: I'm scaling the OOS test set in the same way. That is, I'm calculating the mean and variance based on the in-sample data, then using that mean and variance to scale the OOS data. Your question about whether the mean & SD are similar is something I should have thought to check.